# Installing Hue for an HDInsight HDP cluster

Tags: hadoop, azure-blob-storage, hue, azure-hdinsight, bigdata

I am aware of installing Hue for HDInsight HDP cluster by deploying it on an edge node of the cluter (using a script action, [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-apps-install-custom-applications)), it works fine but asks for the cluster credentials first and then directs me to the Hue login page. Is there a way to get rid of those credentials?
Else, is it possible to deploy Hue on a remote system and then point it to my HDInsight HDP cluster? If so how do I go about?
And which of the above two approaches is better?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding & experience, to answer your questions as below.

1. There is not any way to get rid of those credentials, due to the credential is to authenticate for Resource Management Template deployment, not only for cluster.
2. It's not possible to deploy Hue on a remote system, because of "Hue consists of a web service that runs on a special node in your cluster." as the Hue offical manual said from [here](http://cloudera.github.io/hue/docs-3.5.0/manual.html#_install_hue).

Hope it helps.